# How can I make PhoneGap Camera images with target width and height bigger than 640px of high quality?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, camera

I use Cordova 3.5.0 and the latests version of the [Camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera). I figured out that the image quality drops when I set the targetWidth and targetHeight above 640. Here is the configuration I use:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, 
  { quality : 100,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit : true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 640,
  targetHeight: 640,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true 
});
```

I did several tests capturing photos with the phonegap camera and compared the images that were automatically saved to album.

[Here is the result (targetWidth: 640, targetHeight: 640)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47067729/Foto%2020.11.14%2016%2015%2028%20640.jpg):

[image]

[Here is the result (targetWidth: 800, targetHeight: 800)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47067729/Foto%2020.11.14%2016%2017%2032%20800.jpg):

[image]

[Here is the result (targetWidth: 1280, targetHeight: 1280)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47067729/Foto%2020.11.14%2016%2018%2045%201280.jpg):

[image]

When you click on the links and compare the photos you see that the quality gets worse the bigger the image is.

**How can I make PhoneGap Camera images with target width and height bigger than 640px of high quality?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try not setting the photo height and width in the camera options and manipulate the final image on a canvas element. That way you're working with the best quality image yourself.

Comment: Is this the only way to improve the quality?

Comment: Only way I know of, but I certainly don't know everything!